Django formset queryset
I have two apps: accounting and projects.
Every consumption item has a fk to project.
Every production has a fk to a project.
Production order has fk to production.
produced product has fk to production order.
consumption item has fk to produced product.
While creating produced line, I want to create consumption line as formset. However, consumptionitemline_to_consume field should show instances from the related project, not all instances.. Below I tried to filter the dropdown however, it just does not work.
here is forms
class ProductionProducedLineConsumptionLineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductionProducedLineConsumptionLine
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'productionproducedline': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'produced_kg_scrap': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'w-full input rounded-md'}),
            'produced_kg_wastage': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'w-full input rounded-md'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        production_id = kwargs.pop('production_id', None)  # We'll pass this when initializing the formset in the view
        super(ProductionProducedLineConsumptionLineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if production_id:
            production = ProductionProducedLine.objects.get(id=production_id)
            project = production.productionorderline.production.project
            self.fields['consumptionitemline_to_consume'].queryset = ConsumptionItemLine.objects.filter(project=project) # This does not work?


ProductionProducedLineConsumptionLineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    ProductionProducedLine,
    ProductionProducedLineConsumptionLine,
    fk_name='productionproducedline',
    form=ProductionProducedLineConsumptionLineForm,  # Use the custom form
    fields=('productionproducedline','productionproducedline_to_consume', 'consumptionitemline_to_consume','consumed_kg_product','produced_kg_scrap', 'produced_kg_wastage','wastage_return_customer'),
    extra=1,
    can_delete=True
)



Here is view

class ProductionProducedLineCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ProductionProducedLine
    form_class = ProductionProducedLineForm
    template_name = 'projects/produced_create.html'


    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """Ensure the form is initialized with necessary kwargs."""
        kwargs = super(ProductionProducedLineCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        if self.kwargs.get('order_line_id'):
            kwargs['order_line_id'] = self.kwargs['order_line_id']
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Add formset to context data for rendering in the template."""
        context = super(ProductionProducedLineCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        order_line_id = self.kwargs.get('order_line_id')
        if order_line_id:
            order_line = ProductionOrderLine.objects.get(pk=order_line_id)
            context['order_line'] = order_line
            context['production'] = order_line.production
            context['project'] = order_line.production.project
            if self.request.POST:
                context['formset'] = ProductionProducedLineConsumptionLineFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
            else:
                context['formset'] = ProductionProducedLineConsumptionLineFormSet()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Handle POST requests: Validate both form and formset."""
        self.object = None  # This is required for CreateView to correctly instantiate the form
        form = self.get_form()
        formset = ProductionProducedLineConsumptionLineFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, formset)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, formset)

    def form_valid(self, form, formset):
        """If the form and formset are valid, save the associated models."""
        self.object = form.save()  # Save the ProductionProducedLine instance
        formset.instance = self.object  # Link the formset with the instance
        formset.save()  # Save the formset data
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())  # Redirect to a success page

    def form_invalid(self, form, formset):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, formset=formset))

    def get_success_url(self):
        """Return the URL to redirect to after successful processing."""
        # Adjust this to wherever you want users to be redirected after a successful creation
        return reverse('production-list')


I just lost. Any help is appreciated.
